# can't understand Hoffman Kunze's linear algebra book's proof reasoning

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

In the book [image]

Then
[image]

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind constructing the matrix, I get the unique scalars P_ij part, representing the one basis's vectors with another basis vector's linear combination. But then he uses same matrix for getting another basis's vectors. I'm confused about this kind of reasoning and it appears in other proofs too. How these scalars i's and j's satisfy these equations?
[image]

At this part, he uses same matrix but using j's and i's at the same time. Sorry this question is not clear but in general i am confused about constructing matrix P, can someone explain the reasoning?

Comment: You wrote that you have got the unique scalars $p_{ij}$ then where is the confusion about construction of $P$ I did not understand.

Comment: At the summation notation, we used i'th index and j'th index at the same time. Confusing part is we know i's are unique but we used j's also.